# Can a progressive web app be registered as a share option on iOS?

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps, ios-sharesheet

I plan to develop an app (not sure if I will go with PWA yet) which includes the following "wishlist" scenario:

1. The user is browsing a website he likes using safari, chrome or any browser
2. He clicks the share button in that browser, in order to send the webpage url to another app
3. He selects my PWA
4. This url is saved in the user's wishlist

Is step 3 possible?

Note: someone asked the exact same question here about Android: [Can a progressive web app be registered as a share option in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189160/can-a-progressive-web-app-be-registered-as-a-share-option-in-android)

My question is just the same, except mine is about iOS. I couldn't find any answers to it.

Comment: To appear in the share list your app needs to implement a share extension.  This means it must be a native app, delivered by the App Store.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're describing is covered by [Web Share Target Level 2](https://github.com/w3c/web-share-target/blob/master/docs/explainer.md).

Currently, it [can be used with Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6124071381106688) on some desktop platforms and on Android for installed PWAs.

It's [not available on iOS](https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2020-December/031645.html), unfortunately.