# what is progressive mobile website?

Tags: jquery, html, web, responsive-design

I am working with the responsive website, Which is running on all platforms and various browsers in Mobile, Desktop, Tablet. I noticed this term from a blog

> Progressive Mobile website

Can anyone please share about this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is about a [Progressive Web App](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/), rather than a Progressive Mobile Website

> Progressive Web Apps are user experiences that have the reach of the web, and are:
>
> Reliable - Load instantly and never show the downasaur, even in uncertain network conditions.
>
> Fast - Respond quickly to user interactions with silky smooth animations and no janky scrolling.
> Engaging - Feel like a natural app on the device, with an immersive user experience.
> This new level of of quality allows Progressive Web Apps to earn a place on the users home screen.

Basically, it's a Google initiative to create 'hybrid' like websites that have the some simular functionalities as a native app.

Google has made a [checklist](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/checklist) with points your website should comply to in order to be accepted as a 'progressive web app'. In addition, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39027789/3305454 has a great summary about it.