# What are the business benefits of PWAs

Tags: mobile, native, progressive-web-apps, nativeapplication

I have been trying to understand PWA and the difference between it and web & native apps. Though found many interesting things about the same, I am clueless on what exactly are the benefits of PWA if you are an app development company. Will it help you get better customers? Or it will have no such impact.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this site: [Can Your Company Benefit from a Progressive Web App?](https://www.infoq.com/articles/progressive-web-app-benefits).

> Progressive web apps (PWA) is a new concept that bridges the gap between websites and mobile apps. They promise offline capabilities as well as improved speed and performance.
>
> Benefits of progressive web apps:
>
> - Offline mode
> - Feels like an app, works like a website
> - Improved performance
> - Fast install on devices
> - Push Notifications
> - No app store submission

***Will it help you get better customers?***

I can say yes because increased speed leads to improved user experience and retention rates.

You can also check this related SO post: [What features do Progressive Web Apps have vs. native apps and vice-versa, on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504194/what-features-do-progressive-web-apps-have-vs-native-apps-and-vice-versa-on-an)

> *Progressive Web Apps actually offer more hardware access than commonly thought.*

You can check the link above for more information. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. This is really informative and helped me. Thanks for your time

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I joined Google Chrome dev summit in SF last year. Lyft try to implement PWA version because it help user make a first call easier. At the first time people not want to download any application because it take time at least 1 mins. In this case PWA will help to solve it and after user try PWA Lyft can push msg to ask user to install native app version later.