# PWA feature list for each browser

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Where can I find list of PWA features that are supported and under development for each browser?
This will greatly help to determine if I shall develop a native app or go directly for PWA. And also know upfront what to expect in the foreseeable future in terms of browser support so that I can enhance my app with newer features.

Thanks

Comment: You can check the support for Web App Manifest and Service Workers (main ones) here https://caniuse.com/#search=Web%20App%20Manifest and here https://caniuse.com/#search=Service%20Workers

Answer (score 8):

Actually you can try 
https://whatwebcando.today/
for test your browser first

Comment: This doesn't answer the question while promoting dubiously informed services.

Comment: can we unvote this admin

Answer (score 7):

[Web App Manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json#Browser_compatibility), and 
[Service Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)
 seem to be the key technologies to watch. Google's [Progressive Web App Checklist](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/checklist) mentions both of these technologies.

However, other technologies such as [BeforeInstallPromptEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent), or PWA installation notifications, are explicitly discouraged by Mozilla Developer Network, MDN:

> Do not use it [`BeforeInstallPromptEvent`] on production sites facing the Web

Also, as an aside, commercial incentives for PWA's appear to exist:

> The Supreme Court signaled Apple could face a revived antitrust
>   lawsuit over its price control [...and 30% take] of the iPhone and
>   iPad App Store. -[Fortune](http://fortune.com/2018/11/26/apple-lawsuit-antitrust-supreme-court-app-store-iphone-ipad/)

[Google indicates](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/#what_is_a_progressive_web_app) that a progressive web app, PWA, is:

> - **Progressive - Works for every user, regardless of browser choice** because it's built with progressive enhancement as a core tenet.
> - Responsive - Fits any form factor: desktop, mobile, tablet, or whatever is next. Connectivity independent - Enhanced with service
>     workers to work offline or on low-quality networks.
> - App-like - Feels like an app, because the app shell model separates the application functionality from application content .
> - Fresh - Always up-to-date thanks to the service worker update process.
> - Safe - Served via HTTPS to prevent snooping and to ensure content hasn't been tampered with.
> - **Discoverable - Is identifiable as an "application"** thanks to W3C manifest and service worker registration scope, allowing search
>     engines to find it.
> - Re-engageable - Makes re-engagement easy through features like push notifications.
> - **Installable** - Allows users to add apps they find most useful to their home screen **without the hassle of an app store**.
> - Linkable - Easily share the application via URL, does not require complex installation.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this [blog](http://blog.ionic.io/what-is-a-progressive-web-app/) about the features of PWA. Also based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/getting-started-pwa), Chrome, Opera and Firefox have all implemented support for service worker with Edge having positive public signals about interest in the feature. Safari briefly mentioned interest in it via one engineer's proposed [five year plan](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/FiveYearPlanFall2015). You can also check this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504194/what-features-do-progressive-web-apps-have-vs-native-apps-and-vice-versa-on-an) for more information.