# Can I ask for read SMS in website

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to ask to user for permission to **read sms** of OTP on *web app* such as like android.

If it is possible then ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, progressive web apps and/or HTML5 API can't read or send SMS. Things have not moved a lot since [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504194/what-features-do-progressive-web-apps-have-vs-native-apps-and-vice-versa-on-an)

Answer (score 7):

I was also looking for a way to read SMS from a browser and I end up finding out that support for the [OTPCredential](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OTPCredential) is finally getting traction. Here's a snippet from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OTPCredential#examples):

```js
navigator.credentials.get({
  otp: { transport:['sms'] },
  signal: ac.signal
}).then(otp => {
  input.value = otp.code;
  if (form) form.submit();
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

If you want to see the full code example MDN currently provides, you [can access it here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/web-otp)

Currently, according to [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_otpcredential) there is some browser support for ***OTPCredential API***, but it's  a *non-standard feature and should not be used without careful consideration*

[image]

Hopefully it helps other people as well...

Comment: It seems SMS should has specific pattern :  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebOTP_API

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/sysapps/messaging) is the W3C repo for Messaging API(which is used for sending SMS) and there is no progress for years and the API is [still in proposal stage](https://whatwebcando.today/sms.html). So on hope for anytime soon.