# Build PWA application for Android Mobile

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, hybrid

I am new in PWA application development. I would like to develop PWA application using Angular 6. Any one please suggest for following questions

```
1) How can we create PWA application for Android using Angular 6 ?
2) How can i install PWA application android phone (Local Testing) ?
3) What are features will not work in PWA application in Android and IOS comparing to native?
```

Please suggest !!! Great ! Thanks In Advance

Comment: You are sort of asking for a tutorial. Those you can find plenty of with some Google research. IMHO Max Schwarzmueller has one of the best. If there is a particular problem this would be where you ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

PWA is nothing but a responsive website with a manifest and a service worker, manifest provides the functionality such as an icon, app name, add to home screen options, while service worker provides you a lot of functionality like network calls, notifications etc.

Here are some reference links which you can visit:

https://blog.angulartraining.com/progressive-web-apps-for-angular-6-and-beyond-f7e4b9a2f9fa

https://medium.com/@joseant.ruizsantiago/building-a-pwa-with-angular-6-5735d7308d25

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/

https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/

https://serviceworke.rs/

https://medium.com/dev-channel/why-progressive-web-apps-vs-native-is-the-wrong-question-to-ask-fb8555addcbb

http://www.learncodeonline.in/blog/list-of-top-advantages-disadvantages-of-progressive-web-apps/

Regarding your question about features of PWA vs Native, please see the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39027789/2520628) on stack overflow itself.

Comment: i followed this https://medium.com/@joseant.ruizsantiago/building-a-pwa-with-angular-6-5735d7308d25 but its not adding any PWA file like manifest.json/adding service etc. Can you please suggest

Comment: https://medium.com/dev-channel/learn-how-to-build-a-pwa-in-under-5-minutes-c860ad406ed and https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use pwabuilder https://www.pwabuilder.com/
a project founded by microsoft, community guided.

It does a awesome job for android PWA/TWA

other alternative is bubblewrap